# Is there a way to get the messages count which are pending for a subscription?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I certainly know that there is a property known as ActiveMessages in management client that gives the count of all active messages. But what i want to know is the pending messages

```
 var runTimeInfo = await Helpers.ManagementClient.GetSubscriptionRuntimeInfoAsync(topicName, 
 subscriptionName);
 var messageCount = runTimeInfo.MessageCountDetails.ActiveMessageCount;
```

Pending messages are the ones which are not yet picked up by any subscriber of my subscription.

Context -

Imagine a scenario where my subscriber is picking up the message and doing some long running operation. Now I have scaled up the infrastructure depending upon the message count. The logic to scale up infra is timer trigger azure function which runs every 30 seconds.

The problem is even though my message is picked up by subscriber the active message count is not reduced and it creates problem in my logic of scaling up the infra.

So what i ideally need is PendingMessageCount i.e ActiveMessageCount - MessagesThatareUnderProcess.

Let me know  if you have came across this situation before

Answer (score 0):

Active message count will be reduced only when the peeked messages are completed.
The decision to scale up or down should not be based on the metric of the number of active messages in a queue for a given point in time, but the trend over a period of time. E.g. did the number of messages over the last 3 minutes went up or down.

Comment: Thanks sean, I did the trend thing like you mentioned but was a bit surprised that the property like this is not available with service bus.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a subscriber will be processing one message at a time. So, if you can figure out how many subscribers are configured to pick messages from the subscription at any given point in time,

you can assume 'MessagesThatAreUnderProcess' to be equal to the number of subscribers.

So based on that, 'PendingMessageCount' = 'ActiveMessageCount' - 'NumberOfSubscribers'